# Rails-SQLite-test- Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ unlink_internal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, windows-7, sqlite

rake aborted!
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ unlink_internal - c:/kamal-p/memoryrealive/db
/test.sqlite3

Please tell me how to  solve this problem. If I have to copy develeopment.sqlite3 to test.sqlite3 and rename it, then how to do it

I am using windows 7. and trying to run rake spec and rake db:test:prepare and getting the same error.

my database.yml ---

here is a link to my database.yml
  https://gist.github.com/kamal-github/0d84975cb490968d711b